# ArcMap Symbology: Assign Color by one attribute, symbol by other attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I've got a question concerning the symbology in ArcMap.

I want to use the Unique values/Many fields option to assign unique values based on three attribute fields. To symbolize the first attribute field, I would like to use a color, the second and third attribute field shall use a symbol. Obviously, this can easily be done manually, but as I have nearly 1000 unique values, I was wondering whether there is a possibility to assign the color first, and then the symbols to each same combination, without having to click every item individually.

I hope I have been clear about what I want to do.

I am running ArcGIS 10.2 Basic, and do not know much, or rather nothing, about python.

Edit:

The answers so far do not seem to work properly for me. Therefore, I will try to be more clear with what I need.

I have got a point-shape with 3 fields and 988 features. I want to make a layer of this to apply to different shapes afterwards.

So here is what I want:

- Every unique value (13 unique values) of the first field to have the same color
- Every unique value (4 unique values) of the second field to have the same symbol
- Every unique value (18 unique values) of the third field to have the same symbol
- The different symbols for the second and third field must not superpose each other

I do know how to realise this manually, but I do not want to choose and click every single one of 988 features in the symbology window, especially as they cannot be sorted by the second or third field.

[image: Example]

Is there any possibility to automatically assign colours to the values of one field and symbols to the values of another field?

Comment: You might consider adding a field and populating it with the different symbol values, using the field calculator or a join to a table from another program.  You can also in the Layer-Properties-Symbology-Categories symbology window select multiple layers, right click and choose from several options to apply properties to all the selected entities, including colors.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely do as Johns describes and create an additional field to be your symbol field based on the other three attributes.
This could be done by using the [field calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000) with VB or python. Set the parser as Python,  Click "Show Codeblock" For example:

Using if and else statements you can populate your new symbology field with integers or text. Based on this text, you can set your symbology

```
def symbology (field1, field2, field3):
 #if your 1st field is equal to "sometext" and field 2 is equal to 0.25 populate symbology field with one
  if (field1 == "sometext" and field2 == 0.25):
    return 1
  elif (field1 == "PINE" and field3 > 10):
    return 2
   #if none of the above conditions are met, return 3
  else:
    return 3
```

under your new field = write:

```
symbology(!field1!, !field2!, !field3!)
```

As an additional note, make sure none of your if/else conditions overlap or your won't get the correct values!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I get back to work next week. The code could be helpful, I cannot oversee this, as I have no experience with python or vb.

Answer (score 0):

Wanting different colors for your symbology makes this difficult. However, if you don't mind the color portion of your symbol to be always the same shape (say, a circle that fits within your other two symbols), I would simply add the layer to your table of contents three times, and assign symbology by one of your attributes for each layer.